# how to fix Authorization error on google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying google apps script for the first time and running the below script from google apps script documentation

```
function createAndSendDocument() {
  // Create a new Google Doc named 'Hello, world!'
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('Hello, world!');

  // Access the body of the document, then add a paragraph.
  doc.getBody().appendParagraph('This document was created by Google Apps Script.');

  // Get the URL of the document.
  var url = doc.getUrl();

  // Get the email address of the active user - that's you.
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  // Get the name of the document to use as an email subject line.
  var subject = doc.getName();

  // Append a new string to the "url" variable to use as an email body.
  var body = 'Link to your doc: ' + url;

  // Send yourself an email with a link to the document.
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);
}
```

but when I run it I got an error Error: invalid_client when continuing to authorization required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works, what exact procedure did you use ?

have you seen the authorization request popup ?

are you logged in with a gmail account ?

is the message you write in your post the exact error message ?

Can you have a look at the execution transcript ? (see below)

[image]

Comment: Yes I logged in gmail. Yes I saw the authorization request popup but when i clicked on continue it shows me an error Error: invalid_client                                                                                       I tried execution transcript but it shows me a blank window of execution transcript.

Comment: Error: invalid_client                                                                  Request Details
cookie_policy_enforce=false
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://mail.google.com/ https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents
response_type=code gsession
redirect_uri=https://script.google.com/oauthcallback
access_type=offline
approval_prompt=force
state=ACjPJvHXjr0fueAIE7-4DWYNvFI0Y7WJQ5M9VX0erjmp9-bgN36ZQQrssmCj3923izTRaPCyvWF7CotAh7fVW7yT3CSHKe2wYB90cok2kSkTbhEu3p0t85A
client_id=818760124503@developer.gserviceaccount.com
authuser=0
hl=en

Comment: cookie_policy_enforce=false ... does your browser refuse all cookies ?

Comment: no my browser not refusing any cookie, several site even google and facebook storing cookie in my browser(chrome). I tried in the firefox too but same things happening.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, in my test it worked directly without any issue. sorry

Comment: should i do anything in google (gmail,drive) account settings? and what do u recommend to do by me like creating a new gmail account or something that can remove this error. btw thanks for ur reply.

Comment: Trying on another gmail account would indeed be a solution but it won't solve the original issue you have. I'd suggest you post your issue on the issue tracker with the script ID to get attention from the Google team. It won't probably be instantaneous but they will be able to help more efficiently.

Comment: try this possible solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031107/google-apps-script-calendar-authorization-required-loop/20033077#20033077

Comment: GUYS THANKS FOR HELP, BUT MAY BE GOOGLE FIXED IT. ITS WORKING NOW NORMALLY WITHOUT DOING ANY EXTRA WORK.

Answer (score 0):

I’m getting the same error, and I found an issue logged at https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3414. It looks like this is affecting a lot of users trying to authorise a new script at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the script editor, select Resources > Use Google APIs....
2. Click "Google APIs Console." link
3. select APIs & auth > Registered apps
4. register your script project as web application
5. select Certificate > Generate New Key

It works for me.